# What is the difference of using TemporalAmount or TemporalUnit in Java 8?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I write some piece of code in Java 8 which use time arithmetic.
I realize that I can implement in differentways. Lets look at simple code below. Of course it is the same result but I confused which way is mostly applied or most efficient to make arithmetic operations in Java 8 ?

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
// 1st way
LocalTime plusOp = time.plus(Duration.ofMinutes(10L));
// 2nd way
LocalTime plusOp2 = time.plus(10L, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
System.out.println(plusOp);
System.out.println(plusOp2);
// 3. way simply
 time.plusMinutes(10L);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`Duration` can only handle fixed-length periods, such as "hours", "minutes", "seconds", "days" (where it assumes exactly 24 hours per day). You can't use "months" with `Duration`, because a month varies in length.

`Period` - the other common `TemporalAmount` implementation - represents years, months and days separately.

Personally I would recommend:

- When you know the unit beforehand, use the appropriate `plusXxx` method, e.g. `time.plusMinutes(10)`. That's about as easy to read as it gets.
- When you're trying to represent "logical" calendar amounts, use `Period`
- When you're trying to represent "fixed length" amounts, use `Duration`

Here's an example of where `Period` and `Duration` can differ:

```
import java.time.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
        // At 2015-03-29T01:00:00Z, Europe/London goes from UTC+0 to UTC+1
        LocalDate transitionDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 29);
        ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of(transitionDate, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, zone);
        ZonedDateTime endWithDuration = start.plus(Duration.ofDays(1));
        ZonedDateTime endWithPeriod = start.plus(Period.ofDays(1));
        System.out.println(endWithDuration); // 2015-03-30T01:00+01:00[Europe/London]
        System.out.println(endWithPeriod);   // 2015-03-30T00:00+01:00[Europe/London]
    }
}
```

I wouldn't worry about the efficiency until you really need to - at which point you should have a benchmark so you can test different options.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source, the `plus(long amountToAdd, TemporalUnit unit)` method uses the `plusXXX` methods to produce the results. So there are no arguments here about efficiency.

Instead, you use whichever is most appropriate for your scenario. I would suggest that if you are using user input to decide whether to add hours, minutes, etc., then the `plus()` method is better. Otherwise, your code might be easier to read if you use `plusXXX`.

Comment: Days is not counted in Duration it's period https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html