# Why isn't there a Duration.ofWeeks()?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28963259/3748908), there isn't a `Duration.ofMonths()`

> because a month varies in length.

But why isn't there a `Duration.ofWeeks()`? A week doesn't vary in length, at least no more than a day varies in length. And we do have a `Duration.ofDays()`.

So, is there a strong reason for this?

Comment: Perhaps dividing by `7` was considered something the caller could do.

Comment: A week does vary in length. Basically, you can only use a `Duration` for fixed length, like seconds or hours. A day works because it is estimated to be 24 hours (although it doesn't have a strict fixed length). The contract was loosened a bit for that I assume. This makes the question opinion-based I'm afraid.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Then having `ofNanos()`, `ofMillis()`, `ofSeconds()`, `ofMinutes()` and `ofHours()` seems redundant.

Comment: So the question should rather be “Why is there an `ofDays`?”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all APIs, a line has to be drawn somewhere. Allowing `Duration` to refer to days is strictly speaking dubious, as days vary in length. However, many applications make a conscious decision to refer to 24-hour days, thus the API method was justified.

By contrast, the number of people who think of weeks as (24 * 7) hours is very low. The correct way to model a week is very definitely to use `Period`. As such, while a method could be added to `Duration`, it would likely lead to more mistakes than happiness.